# Asp.net class library core give reference to a web form app

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I want to try web form app .net framework but I wrote backend with .netcore so how can I give reference to .net framework

Comment: asp.net webforms is not supported on .net core or .net 5. you could write your backend as a web service called by your webforms app. you could also, if its .net standard compatible, make your backend a .net standard library.

Comment: If you want .net,runtime as opposed to .net core?  Then start a new project as .net, and then simple import all of your .net core code. 99% of it should run un-changed.